# this.redirect load only blank page

Tags: meteor, iron-router

This code works good

```
  {
        action: function() {
            this.render('userprofile');
        },
        onBeforeAction: function() {
                this.redirect('/mypage');
        }
    });
```

But no such

```
{
    action: function() {
        this.render('userprofile');
    },
    onBeforeAction: function() {
        if (Meteor.user().profile.uname == this.params.uname) {
            this.redirect('/mypage');
            this.stop();
        } else {
            this.next()
        }
    }
});
```

And

```
if (Meteor.user().profile.uname == this.params.uname) {
      this.redirect('/mypage')
} else {
    this.next() 
}
```

If you enter incorrect `uname` this condition work

```
 } else {
                this.next()
            }
```

And if it is true

```
if (Meteor.user().profile.uname == this.params.uname) {
                this.redirect('/mypage');
                this.stop();
            }
```

Page only changes the link from */StevePi* (correct uname) to */mypage* but not render

I tried to use `Router.go()` and other methods , but it did not help :(

Comment: why are you calling this.stop()? Also, are you validating that Meteor.user().profile.uname is actually calling something? Are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this is the case (maybe it will help someone):

```
Router.route('/:uname', function() {
if (Meteor.user().profile.uname == this.params.uname) {
    window.location.href = "/mypage"; <---------------------------------
} else {
    this.render('userprofile')
}
});
```